# How to get the parameter values of a Controller Action in an Exception Filter - ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I have a simple `DemoController` that has an endpoint `Greeting(string message)` with a message parameter. The endpoint will throw an exception sometimes so that the custom [Exception Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-6.0#exception-filters) will catch it.

```cs
public class DemoController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("greeting")]
    public ActionResult Greeting(string message)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        if (random.Next() % 2 == 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("Testing");
        }

        return Ok("Hello");
    }
}
```

I want to generate a log message in the exception filter that includes the parameters of the controller and its values. For example, for the request `GET https://localhost:5000/demo/greetings?message=Hola`, I want to generate a message that looks like: "Error in Greetings at DemoController with Parameters: [message: Hola]".

The exception filter has a [OnException(ExceptionContext) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filters.iexceptionfilter.onexception?view=aspnetcore-6.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-filters-iexceptionfilter-onexception(microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-filters-exceptioncontext)) that will be invoked when the controller throws the testing exception. I cannot find anywhere in the [ExceptionContext class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filters.exceptioncontext?view=aspnetcore-6.0) the values of the parameters in the endpoint. Once I go to the [ActionDescriptor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.abstractions.actiondescriptor?view=aspnetcore-6.0) in the context object, I can see we have a list of [ParameterDescriptor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.abstractions.parameterdescriptor?view=aspnetcore-6.0) objects and I'm able to find the parameter named "message" from the `DemoController`, but I cannot find its value.

The only way I can get the value is using the [BindingInfo.BindingSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.bindingsource?view=aspnetcore-6.0) property to determine where we need to search the value and then inspect the HTTP request directly to look for the parameter value. Basically, I'm manually performing model binding. I have something like this:

```cs
public class MyExceptionFilter : IExceptionFilter
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        var resultObj = new
        {
            error = new
            {
                message = e.InnerException?.Message ?? e.Message,
                exception = e.InnerException?.GetType().Name ?? e.GetType().Name,
            },
        };
        context.Result = new ObjectResult(resultObj)
        {
            StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError
        };
        context.ExceptionHandled = true;

        //  Log error message
        string message = GetErroLogMessage(context);
        Log.Error(message);
    }

    // Gets generic error message to log information about the controller action and its parameters
    private static string GetErroLogMessage(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        //  Initialize string builder for 256 characters
        StringBuilder errorMessage = new StringBuilder(256);

        //  Get controller name and action name to add to the log message
        var actionDesc = context.ActionDescriptor;

        string actionName = actionDesc.RouteValues.ContainsKey("action") ?
            actionDesc.RouteValues["action"] :
            "<ACTION NAME NOT AVAILABLE>";
        string controllerName = actionDesc.RouteValues.ContainsKey("controller") ?
            actionDesc.RouteValues["controller"] :
            "<CONTROLLER NAME NOT AVAILABLE>";

        errorMessage.Append($"Error in {actionName} at {controllerName}Controller. ");

        //  Add parameters to the log message
        errorMessage.Append($"Params: [");

        if (actionDesc.Parameters.Any())
        {
            // --> HERE'S WHERE I NEED THE PARAMETER VALUE
            errorMessage.Append(string.Join("; ", actionDesc.Parameters.Select(param => $"{param.Name}: {GetParameterValue(param, context.HttpContext) ?? "NULL"}")));
        }
        else
        {
            errorMessage.Append("NONE");
        }

        errorMessage.AppendLine("]");

        return errorMessage.ToString();
    }

    //  Reads the HTTP request based on model binding to get the value of the parameter
    private static object GetParameterValue(ParameterDescriptor param, HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        BindingSource bindingSource = param.BindingInfo.BindingSource;
        if (bindingSource.IsFromRequest)
        {
            HttpRequest request = httpContext.Request;
            if (string.Equals(bindingSource.DisplayName, "Query", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                //  Read the parameter from the query string
                IQueryCollection queryString = request.Query;
                object paramValue = queryString.ContainsKey(param.Name) ? queryString[param.Name] : (object)null;
                return paramValue;
            }

            if (string.Equals(bindingSource.DisplayName, "Header", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                //  Read the parameter from request headers
                IHeaderDictionary headers = request.Headers;
                object paramValue = headers.ContainsKey(param.Name) ? headers[param.Name] : (object)null;
                return paramValue;
            }

            if (string.Equals(bindingSource.DisplayName, "Route", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                //  Read the parameter from the routes
                RouteValueDictionary routeValues = request.RouteValues;
                object paramValue = routeValues.ContainsKey(param.Name) ? routeValues[param.Name] : (object)null;
                return paramValue;
            }

            return $"<CANNOT READ FROM SOURCE {bindingSource.DisplayName ?? "NULL"}>";
        }

        return "<CANNOT BIND FROM OUTSIDE THE HTTP REQUEST>";
    }
}
```

What's interesting is that I can see that the variable `message` has the value "Hola" in the controller action `Geeting()`, so technically ASP.NET has already inspect the HTTP Request and assign the value to the variable message, but I don't see it the Exception Filter.

**Is it possible to get the value of the variable message that ASP.NET has already calculated in the exception filter?**

Answer (score 1):

Add these few lines of code to the first of your method to give you a list of parameters as a string

```
private static string GetErroLogMessage(ExceptionContext context)
 {
    var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    stringBuilder.Append("Parameters :[");
    foreach (var item in context.ModelState.Keys)
    {
      stringBuilder.Append($"{item}:{context.ModelState[item]?.RawValue} ,");
    }
     stringBuilder.Append("]");
     string parameters = stringBuilder.ToString();
     //The output is as follows : parameters:[foo:bar]

     //Continuation of previous codes...    
 }
```

Comment: Works with query parameters as expected but the ModelState object is empty when we read from the body of the request.